# Make link translatable in Admin from a PHP string in a tpl-file

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

In a custom `user-login-block.tpl.php` file i want to make a link in the *Create an Account* -button which links to `/doctor/register`. [Here](http://www.bo-medical.com/benl/producten/injectables) the link to the example page (*you are redirected to this page from specific nodes who needs permission* (by Content Access module).

How do i make this link in PHP so i am able to make it multilingual and translate it in `Administration » Configuration » Regional and language » Translate interface` to:

- `benl/doctor/register` (for Belgium dutch site)
- `befr/doctor/register` (for Belgium French site)

I think i need somehow the `base_url` because otherwise it gives the string from the restricted page (in this example `benl/producten/injectables`).

How do i manage this?

**Update:**

To make it more clear this is my HTML:

```
<div class="well">
    <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="HERE THE LINK"><?php print t('Create an Account'); ?></a>
</div>
```

So where is written **HERE THE LINK** i have to insert the php-code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use path aliases for this. Go to /admin/config/search/path/add and create a new alias with the following settings:

- Language: Dutch (or whatever it is called in your site)
- Existing system path: 'doctor/register'
- Path alias: 'dokter/registreer' (or whatever suits your fancy)

Repeat for the French site. Drupal core and contrib modules should automatically pick up the language-dependent aliases. If you're creating a link in a template yourself, make sure you use the l() function to build the entire `<a>` tag. To get the result in your question, you need something like this:

```
<div class="well">
  <?php
    $link_options['attributes']['class'] = array('btn', 'btn-large',' btn-primary');
    print l(t('Create an Account'), 'doctor/register', $link_options);
  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: and how do i place above exactly in the `<a href=""` ?

Comment: @MeesFrenkelFrank – This will create the whole anchor automatically. You can also add classes like so: `<?php l(t('Create an account'), 'doctor/register', array('attributes' => array('class' => 'doc-reg-link'))); ?>`.

Comment: @leymannx i update my question. I added my `HTML`. How do i integrate your example?

Comment: @MeesFrenkelFrank `<div class="well"><?php print l(t('Create an Account'), 'doctor/register'); ?></div>`

Comment: Thanks for your additions, @leymannx. I updated the answer to match the updated question.